# Left and right quotation marks aren't correct when using fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, punctuation

Using XeLaTeX the following document produces the correct result if `\setmainfont{Arial}` is never called (the quotation marks are proper left- and right-quotation marks). Once I try to set a font (even if it has the proper glyphs!) the output appears improperly as ``` ``Quote me!'' ```.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
``Quote me!''
\end{document}
```

Comment: Set the `Ligatures=TeX` feature for the font: `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}`

Comment: Interesting: this solves the problem in Windows TeXstudio where I created the example, but on my Ubuntu machine I get the error: `! Package xkeyval Error: 'TeX' undefined in families 'Ligatures'.`

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date TeX system (e.g. TeX Live) or are you using the one that comes with Ubuntu?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I installed `texlive`. Should be up to date.

Comment: @aardvarkk No, I mean did you install TeX Live from TUG ('stand alone') or using the Ubuntu package system?

Comment: @JosephWright I installed from the package system. After taking a gander through the `fontspec` documentation, I found that `Ligatures=TeX` seems to be associated with LuaTeX? Instead, I switched to `\fontspec[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}` as recommended by the documentation and it magically works!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'd be happy to give you credit if you want to post an answer! I ended up having to go with `Mapping=tex-text`, but same idea.

Comment: @aardvarkk Thank you. I've added an answer.

Comment: As an aside, in a future version of fontspec I plan to make `Ligatures=TeX` the default except when using `\setmonofont`. (Configurable, of course.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `Ligatures=TeX` feature for the font:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
```

with old versions of `fontspec` you should use

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
```

instead. The later with also work with newer versions, but the former is recommended for better compatibility with LuaTeX documents.

A sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
``Quote me!''
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Try using `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}`, which should work on older versions as well.

Comment: It should be `Ligatures=TeX`, with newer versions of `fontspec`

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2021, but the `fontspec` package has done like this for a long time, the given example works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
``Quote me!''
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` declarations inherit `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` unless countermanded before issuing the commands.

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me, but the following bit did the trick:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The given example works for me out of the box.