# Does XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2015 force unicode quotation marks?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Using `XeLaTeX` in TeX Live 2015 seems to break classic LaTeX quotations (or force unicode entry, depending on how one looks at it).

## Results

### TeX Live 2014

fontspec.sty    2015/03/14 v2.4c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

``` ``something quoted'' ``` appears as “something quoted”

### TeX Live 2015

fontspec.sty    2016/01/30 v2.5 Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

``` ``something quoted'' ``` appears as ``something quoted''.

Is this normal? I saw this question: [Left and right quotation marks aren't correct when using fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158983/left-and-right-quotation-marks-arent-correct-when-using-fontspec), but nothing has changed in my source code. Adding `Ligatures=TeX` as a parameter to `\setmainfont` seems to fix the issue, but why just in TeX Live 2015?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
``check it out''
“check it out”
\end{document}
```

## Release Notes for `fontspec`

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/?lang=en

### v2.5a (2016/02/01) "bugs fixed"

- Rather embarrassing bug fix! (`unicode-math` was broken.)
- Remember to add the `fontspec.cfg` file to the distribution.
- Remove `+trep` from `Ligatures=TeX` (no longer necessary).
- Add some basic tests using `l3build`; more to come.
- Simplify some internal Lua code and package loading code.

### v2.5 (2016/01/30) "TL2016 re­lease"

- Provide a new Unicode font encoding ("TU") to replace EU1/EU2 and xunicode. If this causes problems, load fontspec with the `[euenc]` option to revert to the old behaviour.
- New command `\emfontdeclare` for defining font shapes when arbitrarily nesting the `\emph` command.
- Allow slanted small caps and better internal methods for "combining" font shapes; this fixes a few bugs.
- Incorporate "new" font script tags for Indic fonts. E.g., when selecting `Script=Bengali`, fontspec will first query the font for the `bng2` OpenType script, and if not found select `beng`.
- Restrict some font features from being able to be used within `\addfontfeatures` that were causing some font-loading confusion.
- Fixed behaviour in which `\baselineskip` and `\f@size` would (possibly) change values after loading the packge.
- Remove copy of `fixltx2e`'s code for footnote symbols; handled by LaTeX2e now.
- Deprecate `ExternalLocation` for the simpler (and identical) `Path` option.
- Improvement to some warnings/info messages.
- Improve structure of code.

Comment: I get exactly the same for the two lines with an up-to-date TL 2015. What fonts are included in your pdf? It should be `LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C`

Comment: @Herbert It happens when switching fonts. The issue occurs with DejaVu  Sans. This code works fine in 2014.

Comment: Have you updated to the very latest version of fontspec? There was a bug, quickly corrected, in the second-to-last release.

Comment: @macmadness86: works also fine with DejaVu and up-to-date TL

Comment: Version 2.5 forgot to add `fontspec.cfg`, where `Ligatures=TeX` is specified as default feature. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=27244271#27244271

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a bug that has been fixed in a release issued before the question was made

Comment: @egreg Ok, I voted to close it. That designation "off-topic" still needs to be changed to something like "bug already fixed". The question itself is clearly on topic. What i mean is that it was deemed off-topic after the fact. A truly off-topic question will be off-topic at all points in time.

Comment: For anybody who is struggling with figuring this out, it is very "on topic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fontspec` v2.5a (2016/02/01) "bugs fixed" solves the issue.

- Version 2.5 did not include `fontspec.cfg` where `Ligatures=TeX` was specified as a default feature.

`Ligatures=TeX` is a default option for fonts loaded by `fontspec` normally. I therefore did not specify it as a parameter in my documents. In TeX Live 2015, **it accidentally became non-default**. This meant that LaTeX was not creating ligatures out of the character combinations ``` `` ``` and `''`.