# Quotation marks not rendered by XeLaTeX in spite of [Ligatures=TeX]

Tags: xetex, fontspec, quotation

I have a problem with XeLaTeX that I have not had before. Quote marks are not rendering as "smart". Here is a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
``Are quote marks working?''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158983/7927) I tried to use `fontspec` to fix it (I am using `fontspec` anyway outside my MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\begin{document}
``Are quote marks working?''
\end{document}
```

But the result was the same.

I only use XeLaTeX occasionally, as regular LaTeX does the job for most of my stuff. I suspect a system update has upgraded TeX Live since the last time I used XeLaTeX.

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 73.2; using 73.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.3; using 1.3
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.13.1; using 2.13.2
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 8.1.1; using 8.2.2
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.40; using 1.6.40
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.2; using 2.14.2
```

Comment: Both your examples work as expected for me. Can you show an image of the output you get. Perhaps you are using TeX Gyre Pagella as the font, in which case the opening and closing quotation marks look identical?

Comment: @AlanMunn I've actually got the image there already. It just renders the backticks and single quotes literally.

Comment: Sorry I must have totally skipped over it!

Comment: show the log-file of your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer done, thanks

Comment: might be related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690449/suddenly-and-is-not-translated-to-curly-quotes-and-en-dash

Comment: You've shown a log file for a `pdflatex` compilation, not `xelatex`.  But I think @UdiFogiel 's comment is likely to be the answer.

Comment: Augh, yeah, I had closed down the session where I was working with my example. When I regenerated it I did it from Emacs and forgot to redo `TeX-engine-set`. I am installing `texlive-meta` now to see what happens.

Comment: Yep, it was a Manjaro issue. Installing `texlive-meta` fixed it. Thanks.